# Can't display Picture

Tags: php, html, css, image

I'm trying to display a picture from MySQL with a data blob, but I have a problem with 2 different data, I have 2 data image with varying data of row, when I check data from id 1 it uses an image from id 1 but when I check data from id 3 it uses an image from id 1 too
[This is my rows with 2 different data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW4Jy.png)

[Button row 1 with id 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHJc.png)

[Button row 2 with id 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uaLM.png)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Cek Foto
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Foto Yang Diambil</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ayam"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pemasukan WHERE id_pemasukan = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img style=" margin: auto; display: block;" height="50%" width="50%"
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['foto'] ).'"/>';
?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                               <td>
                    <!-- Button untuk modal -->
                          <a href="#" type="button" class=" fa fa-edit btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $data['id_pemasukan']; ?>"></a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: Is there a loop around all of the above code that changes the $id variable before/after executing that SQL command?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i think so, but I can't figure it why, btw I have no form at modal is that make a problem?

Comment: The SQL Query uses an `$id` variable to select the record. If that `$id` never changes then the recordset will never change and thus the image will never change. 
It would also be worth noting that this sql query is potentially vulnerable to sql injection.